# I am not able to access host machine from njs script nginx ser is hosted on docker client

Tags: docker, nginx, njs

I have tried with `host.docker.internal`  and it works fine inside default.conf. However if I use it inside njs script file (using js-content) it is not working.
Here is my default.config file and njs script file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;  # Replace with your domain name or IP address    
    
      location /api1 {       
         
         js_content scripts.apiRouter;      
          
    }
    
     
  location /api2 {
           
          proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5055/WeatherForecast;
         
    }
    
    
}
```

```
function apiRouter(r) {
  ngx.fetch('http://host.docker.internal:5055/WeatherForecast')  // Pass the URL as a string parameter
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
      } else {
        throw new Error('API request failed with status: ' + response.status);
      }
    })
    .then(function(body) {
      ngx.log(ngx.ERR, body); // Log the response data to the error log
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      ngx.log(ngx.ERR, 'Error: ' + error.message); // Log the error message to the error log
    });
}

export default { apiRouter };
```

**/api2** is working fine but accessing api **api1**  gives following error:

> unable to find host host.docker.internal.

Things I have tried already,
I have make my API accessible(172.17.0.1) with http://172.17.0.1:5055/WeatherForecast.However it gives following error,

> 2023-07-11 00:25:00 2023/07/10 18:55:00 [error] 141#141: *11 recv() failed (111: Connection refused), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8008"
> 2023-07-11 00:25:00 2023/07/10 18:55:00 [error] 141#141: *11 js: Error: connect failed.

Please note my container also in same subnet (172.17.0);

```
 "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DriverOpts": null
```

Please help me resolving this issue.